# Public / Internal modifier spawns error: This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI encoder

Tags: solidity, error

I have this code snippet:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.7.0;

import "@aztec/protocol/contracts/libs/NoteUtils.sol";

library EscrowUtils {
    using NoteUtils for bytes;

    struct Note {
        address owner;
        bytes32 noteHash;
    }

    function noteBytesToStruct(bytes memory note)
        internal
        pure
        returns (Note memory codedNote)
    {
        (address owner, bytes32 noteHash, ) = note.extractNote();
        return Note(owner, noteHash);
    }
}
```

which does not throw any errors. However, when I change the visibility modifier on the function to public, I get:

```
This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI encoder. Use "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;" to enable the feature.
```

Why changing modifier causes this error?

Answer (score 1):

Because calling a function which returns a struct is currently not supported:

- From another contract instance
- From an off-chain script or app

Change `returns (Note memory codedNote)` and `return Note(owner, noteHash)`,

To `returns (address, bytes32)` and `return (owner, noteHash)`.

Comment: the issue is that if we use `internal` then for internal calls it is supported, but as soon as we make this function `public` we no longer have the ability to do this?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: What part of the first bullet in my answer did you not understand??? Internal functions can be called only from the same contract instance.